# Android locationManager return NULL value

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

mprovider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

if (mprovider != null && !mprovider.equals("")) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(mprovider);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(mprovider, 1000, 15, SupplierList.this);

    if (location != null)
        onLocationChanged(location);
    else

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Location Provider Found Check Your Code", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Location manager is always returning null value,Can you help me what is the issue in my code?

Comment: Share more code, where is the location listener? The only location i see you trying to access is the last known location which in some cases might be null.

Comment: @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Glat =String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
        Glon =String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
    }